# How do I know when user launches a third party app in android - kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have started learning android very recently and I am writing a small app which just shows a toast message to a user when user opens any app. I tried googling and reading through the doccs but could not find any way to get that information.
Later I found that we can get foreground app info using something called getSystemService()
so I wrote this

```
val runningProcessInfo = mutableListOf<String>()
        val appService : ActivityManager = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val tasks = appService.runningAppProcesses
        for(task in tasks){
            if (task.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
            {
                runningProcessInfo.add(task.processName+"\n")
            }
            Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, runningProcessInfo.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

The second problem is how do I make apps launching in the foreground notify my app .. is there any event which I can subscribe to ? I have tried googling this too but no serious leads there .. Can someone please guide me in a right direction ? thanks :)

Comment: "is there any event which I can subscribe to ?" -- generally, no, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh darn.. is there any alternate way ? How does these app locking apps detect if some app comes to foreground ? Also I am not sure but I read it somewhere that you can use accessibility settings for that but google removes those kind of apps which use accessibility settings for some other reason.

Comment: "I am not sure but I read it somewhere that you can use accessibility settings for that but google removes those kind of apps which use accessibility settings for some other reason" -- Google's policies here are confusing at best. But yes, Google stated that they intended to to remove apps that used accessibility services for non-accessibility reasons. I do not know what their current plans are.